# Error between classes

Tags: c#, oop

To explain my problem I made this code.

The application will run the class `control` and from there it will create the new instances of the two other classes `serial` and `UIcontrol`.

In `UI control` a function will call a function in `control` which will call a function in `serial` which will call a function in `control` which will call a function in `UIcontrol` which will do something else.

I know this is insane but I need this functionality.

```
public class control // My application will enter here
{
    private serial serial_;
    private UIcontrol UIcontrol_;

    public control()
    {
        serial_ = new serial(this);
        UIcontrol_ = new UIcontrol(this);
    }

    public void controlToGUI()
    {
        UIcontrol_.stopHere();
    }

    public void controlToSerial()
    {
        serial_.serialToControl();
    }
}

public class UIcontrol
{
    private static control myParent;

    public UIcontrol(control parent)
    {
        myParent = parent;
        UItoControl();
    }

    public void UItoControl()
    {
        myParent.controlToSerial();
    }

    public void stopHere()
    {
        int i = 2;
    }
}

public class serial
{
    private static control myParent;

    public serial(control parent)
    {
        myParent = parent;
    }

    public void serialToControl()
    {
        myParent.controlToGUI();
    }
}
```

I get the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Test App.exe` when the code reach:

```
    public void controlToGUI()
    {
        UIcontrol_.stopHere(); // This line gives me the error
    }
```

Comment: stophere needs to be static

Comment: `I know this is insane but I need this functionality.` lol. So many possible jokes.

Comment: *"In UI control a function will call a function in control which will call a function in serial which will call a function in control which will call a function in UIcontrol"* - revise your design.

Comment: What are you truing to accomplish? Another thing: why are the names of methods and classes like that? it looks like an strange mix between java,C# and a personal touch

Comment: @MikeCheel that's not true

Comment: I missed seeing where it was instatiated, I see it now.

Comment: My design is exactly as it should be - Its a big application. It's possible that I could have made a better example though.

Comment: @AskMøller really? Because based on your example you have really tight, unnecessary, coupling between `control` and `UIControl`/`serial`. It *seems* like you want aggregation (`UIControl`/`serial` can live independently from `control`) but instead what you have is composition (`UIControl`/`serial` are dependant on `control`).

Comment: @James This is my idea of the software interaction: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sqzzwyu3y082v2x/SW%20overview.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because: `UIcontrol_ = new UIcontrol(this);` did not finish executing, i.e UIcontrol_ is still null.
This is why:
Before assigning the "new UIcontrol(this);" to UIcontrol_ it needs to finish initializing the new object but it doesn't because the constructor is still calling other functions and didn't finish.
What you can do is remove the `UItoControl();` method call from the UIcontrol constructor to be like this:

```
 public UIcontrol(control parent)
{
    myParent = parent;
}
```

and call that method after initializing UIcontrol_: to be like this:

```
public control()
{
    serial_ = new serial(this);
    UIcontrol_ = new UIcontrol(this);
    UIcontrol_.UItoControl();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, thank you :) Maybe I should have mentioned, that i'm very new to c#.

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, but this is common between all Object Oriented languages :)

Comment: Well, I'm a c embedded programmer (and only intermediate). But its quite obvious after you pointed it out.